# Error compiling Spark code: object mapreduce is not a member of package org.apache.hadoop.hbase

Tags: scala, maven, hbase, apache-spark

Edit: I added the hbase dependencies defined in the top level pom file to the project level pom and now it can find the package.

I have a scala object to read data from an HBase (0.98.4-hadoop2) table within Spark (1.0.1). However, compiling with maven results in an error when I try to import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat.

```
error: object mapreduce is not a member of package org.apache.hadoop.hbase
```

The code and relevant pom are below:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes
import org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import java.util.Properties
import java.io.FileInputStream
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat

object readDataFromHbase {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var propFileName = "hbaseConfig.properties"
    if(args.size > 0){
      propFileName = args(0)
    }

    /** Load properties **/
    val prop = new Properties
    val inStream = new FileInputStream(propFileName)
    prop.load(inStream)

    //set spark context and open input file
    val sparkMaster = prop.getProperty("hbase.spark.master")
    val sparkJobName = prop.getProperty("hbase.spark.job.name")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkMaster,sparkJobName )
    //set hbase connection
    val hbaseConf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
    hbaseConf.set("hbase.rootdir", prop.getProperty("hbase.rootdir"))
    hbaseConf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, prop.getProperty("hbase.table.name"))

   val hBaseRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(hbaseConf, classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat], 
    classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable], 
    classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result]
    )
    val hBaseData = hBaseRDD.map(t=>t._2)
    .map(res =>res.getColumnLatestCell("cf".getBytes(), "col".getBytes()))
    .map(c=>c.getValueArray())
    .map(a=> new String(a, "utf8"))

    hBaseData.foreach(println)
  }

}
```

The Hbase part of the pom file is (hbase.version = 0.98.4-hadoop2):

```
        <!-- HBase -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
      <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
      <version>${hbase.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
      <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
      <version>${hbase.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
      <artifactId>hbase-server</artifactId>
      <version>${hbase.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
      <artifactId>hbase-common</artifactId>
      <version>${hbase.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
      <artifactId>hbase-hadoop2-compat</artifactId>
      <version>${hbase.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
      <artifactId>hbase-hadoop-compat</artifactId>
      <version>${hbase.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
      <artifactId>hbase-hadoop-compat</artifactId>
      <version>${hbase.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
      <artifactId>hbase-protocol</artifactId>
      <version>${hbase.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have cleaned the package with no luck. The main thing I need from the import is the classOf(TableInputFormat) to be used in setting the RDD. I suspect that I'm missing a dependency in my pom file but can't figure out which one. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well. For me it is in hbase-server.

Answer (score 1):

`TableInputFormat` is in the `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce`
 packacge, which is part of the [`hbase-server`](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22hbase-server%22) artifact, so you will need to add that as a dependency, like @[xgdgsc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25297155/error-compiling-spark-code-object-mapreduce-is-not-a-member-of-package-org-apac#comment44172330_25297155) commented:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase-server</artifactId>
    <version>${hbase.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

in spark 1.0 and above:

put all your hbase jar into spark/assembly/lib or spark/core/lib directory. Hopefully youhave docker to automate all this.

a)For CDH version, the relate hbase jar is usually under /usr/lib/hbase/*.jar which are symlink to correct jar.

b) good article to read from http://www.abcn.net/2014/07/lighting-spark-with-hbase-full-edition.html